# Highlight the active tab for html mvc 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs, navigation

How do I highlight my active tab in navigation? I have been trying it different ways for hours but none is working right. I know there are some ways to do it like using active, selected and etc but I just can't get it right. Please help.

Here's the code in my css file, with some settings on the tabs control.

```
/* Tab Control */
#tabs ul 
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 270px;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
#tabs ul li 
{
    display: outline-block;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
}
#tabs ul li a {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    color: #6d6e71;
    text-decoration: none;
} 
#tabs ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #eb8c00;
}
#tabs #Content_Area 
{
    margin-left: 270px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:19px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

And my html code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')"><a>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li id="li_tab2" onclick="tab('tab2')"><a>Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Content_Area">
        <div id="tab1">
            <p>This is the text for tab 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" style="display: none;">
            <p>This is the text for tab 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not refreshing page on anchors click then you could highlight tabs using jquery
here is code:

```
$('ul li').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).children().css('color','red');
$(this).siblings().children().css('color','black');
});
```

and jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/338qH/